# Infinite zeros and continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f(x)\cos{x}>0$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\cos{x} \neq 0$.Prove that $f$ has infinitely many zeros and find these roots.

As a first thought,we can write $\mathbb{R}= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}[2n \pi,2n\pi+\pi]$

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.We can see that $$\cos{2n\pi}=1 \Rightarrow f(2n\pi)>0 $$ $$\cos{(2n\pi+\pi)}=-1 \Rightarrow f(2n\pi+\pi)<0$$

Thus we see that $$f(x)>0, \forall x:  2n\pi \leq x<2n\pi+\pi/2$$ $$f(x)<0, \forall x: 2n\pi+\pi/2<x \leq 2n\pi+\pi$$

Assume that $f(2k\pi+\pi/2)>0$. From the continuity of $f$ with $\epsilon=\frac{f(2k\pi+\pi/2)}{2}>0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>\frac{f(2k\pi+\pi/2)}{2}>0, \forall x\in (2n\pi+\pi/2-\delta,2n\pi+\pi/2+\delta)$

But if we take $x_0 : 2n\pi+\pi/2<x_0<2n\pi+\pi/2+\delta$ we see that $f(x_0)<0$ which is a contradiction.

With the same argument we prove that $f(2n\pi+\pi/2)$ cannot be smaller than $0$

Thus $f(2n\pi+\pi/2)=0$ so $2n\pi+\pi/2$ is a zero of $f$ in the interval $I_n=[2n \pi,2n\pi+\pi]$ which is unique in this interval.

Assume that $f$ has finitely many zeros, namely $\{x_1,x_2....x_N\}$.

We know that $x_i=2k_i\pi+\pi/2$ for $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x_i \in I_{k_i}$ respectively fror $i=1,2...N$

Now if we take $m=|k_1|+|k_2|+...+|k_N|+1$ then it is not difficult to see that the interval $I_m=[2m \pi,2m\pi+\pi]$ does not intersect the intervals $I_{k_i}$ for all $i=1,2...N$

Also $F(x_m)=f(2m \pi+\pi/2)=0$ and $2m \pi+\pi/2 \notin I_{k_i},\forall i=1,2...N \Rightarrow x_m \neq x_i, \forall i=1,2...N$ which is a contradiction.

Thus $f$ has infinitely many zeros.

Is my proof correct or am i missing something?

Also i found that a function with the property stated in the beggining is $f(x)=\cos{x}$

Are there any other functions with this property?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over each interval $(\frac{\pi}2+k\pi, \frac{\pi}2+(k+1)\pi)$, $\cos$ has constant sign and is non-zero, so $f(x)\cos(x)>0$, hence $f(x)\neq 0$ and $f(x)$ has same sign as $\cos(x)$.

From one interval to the next, $f$ changes sign (because $\cos$ does), and $f$ is continuous, so $f$ must vanish somewhere. Since $f(x)\neq 0$ if $x\in (\frac{\pi}2+k\pi, \frac{\pi}2+(k+1)\pi)$, $\;f$ is $0$ at each $\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$, and only at these points.

Comment: So do i have to change the intervals in my solution?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin x+2}{\cos x}\, \cos x\quad$.This function does the job but never vanish. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Raffaele $x\mapsto \frac{\sin x+2}{\cos x}$ (if that's what you meant) is not well-defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Absent-minded me... I only thought to the result $\sin x+2$ Thank you for the comment!